# Firebase sometimes returns empty value

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to JavaScript and Web Development. I'm trying to create a website where I load data from a FireBase database. Here is the code block for that function:

```
function getAllAgencies() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        agencies = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      } else {
        alert("Greska prilikom ucitavanja agencije!");
      }
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", firebase + "/agencije.json");
  request.send();
}
```

The data is stored in agencies variable. The problem occurs in the next function:

```
function testCard() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let test = document.getElementsByClassName("card-title");
    let i = 0;
    for (let key in agencies) {
      test[i].textContent = agencies[key]["naziv"];
      i++;

      if (i >= test.length) {
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here I simply want to change the card titles to whatever is in the database, however sometimes the variable agencies is empty and it just passes through the for loop leaving the titles untouched.
Any solutions?

I tried to everything I could, triple-checked the FireBase URL, I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: Most likely the `agencies` variable hasn't been populated yet by the time you use it in `testCard`, so you'll want to check for that in your code with something like `if (!agencies) alert("Agencies not loaded yet")`.